# How do I completely disable SSL on my nginx site?

Tags: nginx, ssl

I'm attempting to set up a NetBox installation. It's going to be completely internal to my network and it's going to have a internal (.local) domain. As such, I don't want to use SSL certificates at all.

I'm very new to nginx and HTTP servers in general, so I'm not clear on how I should change the config files I have. For example, I have the /etc/nginx/nginx.conf file, as well as the config file (just named netbox) in the sites-enabled folder. Are there settings that need to be changed in both? I'll include both files below (with my internal domain name redacted) but if there's any other helpful info I can provide let me know and I'll be happy to do so.

nginx.conf:

```
user www-data;
worker_processes auto;
pid /run/nginx.pid;
include /etc/nginx/modules-enabled/*.conf;

events {
        worker_connections 768;
        # multi_accept on;
}

http {

        ##
        # Basic Settings
        ##

        sendfile on;
        tcp_nopush on;
        types_hash_max_size 2048;
        # server_tokens off;

        # server_names_hash_bucket_size 64;
        # server_name_in_redirect off;

        include /etc/nginx/mime.types;
        default_type application/octet-stream;

        ##
        # SSL Settings
        ##

        ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2 TLSv1.3; # Dropping SSLv3, ref: POODLE
        ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;

        ##
        # Logging Settings
        ##

        access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;
        error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;

        ##
        # Gzip Settings
        ##

        gzip on;

        # gzip_vary on;
        # gzip_proxied any;
        # gzip_comp_level 6;
        # gzip_buffers 16 8k;
        # gzip_http_version 1.1;
        # gzip_types text/plain text/css application/json application/javascript text/xml application/xml application/xml+rss text/javascript;

        ##
        # Virtual Host Configs
        ##

        include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
        include /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*;
}


#mail {
#       # See sample authentication script at:
#       # http://wiki.nginx.org/ImapAuthenticateWithApachePhpScript
#
```

sites-enabled/netbox:

```
server {
    listen [::]:443 ssl ipv6only=off;

    # CHANGE THIS TO YOUR SERVER'S NAME
    server_name [my internal domain is here];

    ssl_certificate /etc/ssl/certs/netbox.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/ssl/private/netbox.key;

    client_max_body_size 25m;

    location /static/ {
        alias /opt/netbox/netbox/static/;
    }

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8001;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $http_host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
    }
}

server {
    # Redirect HTTP traffic to HTTPS
    listen [::]:80 ipv6only=off;
    server_name _;
    return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
}
```

I'm new to this community so if I've violated any rules or anything please let me know and I'll correct it.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Looking at you config, remove the redirect from the http server to the https server. Transfer the relevant parts of the https server into the http server.  Then remove the https server from the config should do the job but perhaps I'm missing something because I don't have any experience wit NetBox. What have you tried and what happened ?

Comment: Just a general tip: The use of .local domain names is fraught. Avoid it if you can. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/.local

Answer (score 1):

sites-enabled/netbox:

```
server {
    listen [::]:80 ipv6only=off;

    # CHANGE THIS TO YOUR SERVER'S NAME
    server_name [my internal domain is here];

    #ssl_certificate /etc/ssl/certs/netbox.crt;
    #ssl_certificate_key /etc/ssl/private/netbox.key;

    client_max_body_size 25m;

    location /static/ {
        alias /opt/netbox/netbox/static/;
    }

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8001;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $http_host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
    }
}
```

Comment: This seems to work and the changes make sense to me.

The site now loads when I navigate directly to the IP, but when I try to go through the local domain I get a bad gateway (400) error.

Comment: What url you input in a browser's address bar?